# Running constant scripts

Tags: php, datetime, toggle, ads

I'm busy coding a website with adverts that have an expiry date. After the expiry date, the ads cannot show on the website anymore. Normally how I run scripts for expiry dates is running it with a login as its trigger. But with ads, I can't wait until someone logs in to check the ads.

There is already loads of JavaScript running on all the pages, so I would rather not add more.....but I will if its necessary.

I'm not sure how to add a script to run constantly using PHP, only using setInterval() in a JS Script.

Comment: What you have tried? Can you show us the relevent part of the code?

Comment: Please provide more information. How do you save the active time period? Seems simple to check the current date/time versus a database in PHP where you save your ads. -- What are you using in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems terribly inconsistent, but it appears that you have the completely wrong approach. To have expiring items, you do not manually deactivate them when the expiry date comes or something like that. You simply have the expiry date as part of the item (say, a column in your database) and you **select items which have not yet expired** when you select items. E.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM `ads` WHERE `expiry_date` > NOW()
```

Comment: I was thinking about it the wrong way completely! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

you mean run the script without reloading/refreshing the page, right? then javascript solution's the best option, as far as i know. Some setInterval to check and perhaps the script  to show hide something in php, but the handler should be java/ajax